# jQuery reverse .animate and trigger?

Tags: jquery

So I have this jQuery code and was wondering if a user were to click on any element on the page this code would reverse, what trigger would this be?

```
$("#cia").click(function() {
$("#re").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
$("#r").animate({
  "margin-top": "104px"
}, 800);
});
```

Comment: this code will be reverse.. what do you mean? the execution of `$(#r)` will come first before `$('#re')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this using `document.click()`, so that every click triggers the animation reversal:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $("#re").animate({
      "margin-top": "0px"
    }, 800);
    $("#r").animate({
      "margin-top": "0px"
    }, 800);
});
```

However, make sure to include [`stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) in your initial click event, as otherwise `document.click()` would be triggered on this (and your animation would 'toggle' downwards and upwards all in one click), too:

```
$("#cia").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#re").animate({
      "margin-top": "104px"
    }, 800);
    $("#r").animate({
      "margin-top": "104px"
    }, 800);
});
```

[**jsFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkQ2r/)

Answer (score 1):

Not a jQuery function but two states (default and reverse) may do the trick.

```
$("#cia").click(function() {
var re = ( document.getElementById('re').style.marginTop > 104 ) ? 104 : 000;
var r = ( document.getElementById('r').style.marginTop > 104 ) ? 104 : 000;    
$("#re").animate({
  "margin-top": re + "px"
}, 800);
$("#r").animate({
  "margin-top": r + "px"
}, 800);
});
```

Replace 000 with the inverse value. If the inverse is less than 104 flip the direction of the >